# Database reading to list<T> for display returning null values for some columns that already have values (asp.net mvc)

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have created a database for saving movie details using an ASP.NET MVC web application. I can add data to the database. Inside the database it is showing values in all columns. But when I retrieve data from the table using this statement

```
return cnn.Query<T>(sql).ToList();
```

the retrieved list contains null values for 6 columns (`C_Category, FilmName, Filmid, D_Cost, P_Cost`) [Poster is also null because I haven't added the code for converting the file upload to bytes. That is to be added] But these 6 columns have their respective values in the database.

Is there any way to correct my code to read from database properly? Can you please suggest anything?

I tried adding a breakpoint at the above return statement and viewed the list, which showed up the error values in it before it is passed to further stages. The project builds without any errors and runs but displays these nulls.

[image]

The following is the SQL Server data access class file's code

```
public static List<T> LoadData<T>(string sql)
{
    using (IDbConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionSring()))
    {
        return cnn.Query<T>(sql).ToList();
    }
}
```

This is my business logic class:

```
public static List<FilmAddModel> LoadFilm()
{            
    string sql = @"select * from dbo.Film;";
    return SqlDataAccess.LoadData<FilmAddModel>(sql);
}
```

And this is my model for dB display and write

```
public class FilmAddModel
{
        public int Filmid { get; set; }
        public string FilmName { get; set; }    
        public string Actor { get; set; }   
        public string Actress { get; set; }       
        public string Pub_Date { get; set; }
        public string Director { get; set; }        
        public string Producer { get; set; }     
        public decimal P_Cost { get; set; }
        public decimal D_Cost { get; set; }   
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string C_Category { get; set; }      
        public byte[] Poster { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my home controller code to use the above for displaying the database contents:

```
public ActionResult ViewFilm()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Movies List";
    var data = LoadFilm();
    List<FilmAddModel> movies = new List<FilmAddModel>();

    foreach (var row in data)               
    {
        movies.Add(new FilmAddModel
                       {
                           Filmid = row.Filmid,
                           FilmName = row.FilmName,
                           Actor = row.Actor,
                           Actress = row.Actress,
                           Pub_Date = row.Pub_Date,
                           Director = row.Director,
                           Producer = row.Producer,
                           P_Cost = row.P_Cost,
                           D_Cost = row.D_Cost,
                           Category = row.Category,
                           C_Category = row.C_Category,
                           Poster = row.Poster  
                       });
    }

    return View(movies);
}
```

Following is my database structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Film] 
(
    [Film_id]       INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [film_name]     VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [actor]         VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [actress]       VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [pub_date]      VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [director]      VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [producer]      VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [prod_cost]     DECIMAL(18) NULL,
    [dist_cost]     DECIMAL(18) NULL,
    [category]      VARCHAR(30) NULL,
    [cert_category] VARCHAR(20) NULL,
    [poster]        VARBINARY(MAX) NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Film_id] ASC)
);
```

Answer (score 3):

The names of your SQL Server table columns and your C# model class don't match - you have e.g. `film_name` in the table, and `FilmName` in the C# model class - same goes for `cert_category` in SQL Server, and `C_Category` in C#.

If you have such differences in name, you need to decorate your C# model class with data annotations - something like:

```
public class FilmAddModel   
{
    [Column("film_id")]
    public int Filmid { get; set; }
    [Column("film_name")]
    public string FilmName { get; set; }    
    public string Actor { get; set; }   
    public string Actress { get; set; }       
    public string Pub_Date { get; set; }
    public string Director { get; set; }        
    public string Producer { get; set; }     
    [Column("prod_cost")]
    public decimal P_Cost { get; set; }
    [Column("dist_cost")]
    public decimal D_Cost { get; set; }   
    public string Category { get; set; }
    [Column("cert_category")]
    public string C_Category { get; set; }      
    public byte[] Poster { get; set; }
}
```

With these data annotations, the mapping should be done properly between the values in your SQL Server table, and the C# model class.

As a side note: the `LoadFilm` method returns a `List<FilmAddModel>` - so why are you creating a **second** `List<FilmAddModel>` in your `ViewFilm` action method and iterate over the list return to add the same type of data into the result list?? You could just simply return the `data` returned from `LoadFilm` - it's already in the "right" shape ....

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I've edited the FilmAddModel with data annotations and added using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema; but still the database is read as previously. I have created 'FilmAddModel' in 2 projects in the same solution. One in the DataLibrary and other in the Webapplication project.

Answer (score 0):

When you converting data to model inside foreach loop you didn’t use the correct name for those field to retrive from database.
Use
C_Category = row.cert_category

Filmid = row.Film_id

etc.
that means according to fieldname inside your data object.